# Extracting inner array in python numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of shape (10,) and each element of that array contains another array of shape (9,9,1). How can I extract the inner array so that my final array has a shape (10,9,9,1).

Currently the array looks like:
`array([array(...), array(...), ...])`

Comment: Try `np.stack(arr)`.  It may fail if those inner arrays aren't all the same shape.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all you need to do is use the `numpy.reshape` method.

```
# Just specify the array you want to reshape, and then a
new_arr = np.reshape(arr, [len(arr), len(arr[0]), len(arr[0][0]), len(arr[0][0][0])])
```

This is my lazy way of doing things because you specified the shape of the `array` and what you want it to be. If you didn't know the dimensions, and you wanted to expand it fully, I'd suggest creating a `list` variable and then using a `while` loop to check to see if the constituents of the `array` are arrays. If they are, you simply go deeper and if they're not, you add that dimension to the `list`. Then you could use that `list` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does not allow you to have a non-rectangular array. If you want to convert a list of arrays into a single array, ALL arrays in the list must have the same shape. If they are all of the same shape, you can convert by:

```
arr = np.stack(your_list)
```